# Filtering on a GraphQL union type with HotChocolate

Tags: graphql, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

Imagine there is a GraphQL endpoint with which you can retrieve files and folders. Files have different properties than folders. I use HotChocolate (12.14.0) and Entity Framework Core (6.0.9) on .NET 6 and have defined my query and objects using a `UnionType` like this:

```
public class Query
{
    [UseOffsetPaging(IncludeTotalCount = true)]
    [UseProjection]
    [UseFiltering]
    [UseSorting]
    public IQueryable<IFileOrFolder> GetFiles([Service] IFilesReadModel filesReadModel)
        => filesReadModel.GetFiles();
}

[UnionType("FileOrFolder")]
public interface IFileOrFolder
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("files")]
public abstract class FileOrFolder : IFileOrFolder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

public class File : FileOrFolder
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}

public class Folder : FileOrFolder
{
    public ICollection<FileOrFolder> Files { get; set; } = new List<FileOrFolder>();
}
```

This generates the following schema (large parts omitted for brevity):

```
type Query {
  ...
  filesAndFolders(
    skip: Int
    take: Int
    where: IFileOrFolderFilterInput
    order: [IFileOrFolderFilterInput!]
  ): FileOrFolderCollectionSegment
  ...
}

input IFileOrFolderFilterInput {
  and: [IFileOrFolderFilterInput!]
  or: [IFileOrFolderFilterInput!]
  id: ComparableInt32OperationFilterInput
  name: StringOperationFilterInput
}
```

As you can see, the generated input `IFileOrFolderFilterInput` enables filtering (`where`) on `Id` and `Name` (the properties that both `File` and `Folder` share and are implemented in the base class `FileOrFolder`), but not on the properties that are specific for `File` or `Folder`, like the `Size` property of `File`.

Is it possible to enable filtering on properties of a union type that are not shared between the individual classes?